# How to implement a Transform stream, which is in different object modes as Readable and Writable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I want to implement a serialization stream, which will take objects (implement `Writable` with `objectMode: true`) and transform them into bytes (implement `Readable` with `objectMode: false`).

In [Implementing a transform stream](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream) section I see that:

> options - Passed to both Writable and Readable constructors

So it looks like it is not supported. But I wonder if it's really a "hard" limitation, and nobody should do it (why?), or it's OK in general, and I am missing other ways of doing this? Is there any examples of such streams?

I need streams to keep application memory bounded. My object's sizes are already bounded, so it's fine to operate in [object mode](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/stream.html#stream_object_mode).

Comment: You actually can set different options for readable and writable parts: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/stream.html#stream_writable_writableobjectmode, https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/stream.html#stream_readable_readableobjectmode

Comment: @georg I knew I'm missing something! I was looking into `ReadableOptions` & `WritableOptions` and missed it.